Type inference error for meta.error from useField hook
I'm working with a Formik form that uses MUI's autocomplete component.  The selected value can either be null or an object. With Yup I'm able to validate the null value using required like so:
jobLevel: Yup.object().required('Job Level is a required field'),
But the options list includes an option labeled None where the id is null. If the field is required, I want to show an error when None is selected, asking the user to pick a valid option. To handle this, I've modified my schema like so.
jobLevel: Yup.object().shape({
  id: Yup.string().nullable().required("Job Level is a required field"),
  label: Yup.string().nullable(),
}).nullable().required("Job Level is a required field")

Now given this schema, the formik error errors.jobLevel could be a string or an object errors.jobLevel.id I'm trying to render both in my autocomplete component using type but I get the following error for meta returned from formik's useField:
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
Here's a link to a minimal codesandbox to demonstrate the issue. The validation schema is in App.tsx, and the type error can be seen in Field.tsx.
Any ideas on how to fix this?
I have tried adding Value to useField to get better type inference but that didn't seem to have helped.
const [field, meta] = useField<Value>(name);
I have also tried using lodash's isObject function to determine the type but that doesn't help either.
if (_.isObject(meta.error) && "id" in meta.error) {
  return meta.error.id;
}

